# AWS ELB Autoscaling group with common filesystem (e.g. EBS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am using AWS [elastic beanstalk with autoscaling group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html)

I wish to log events into files and be able to finish processing the files before instances terminate during a shutdown.

I read that [lifecycle hooks](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/auto-scaling-update-lifecycle-standby-detach/) can answer my requirement.

My question is: is there an alternative like using a common EBS file system for all the instances in the group that will always be kept live. If that is possible, is there any cons using that approach? Is IO slower?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EBS volume can not be attached to several EC2 instances at the same time.

But shared storage is possible with EFS — [Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/). It's pricey, so EFS is not suitable for large amounts of data. But it is as fast as any NFS share and can be mounted to hundreds of servers at the same time.

The only consideration is how you will mount EFS volume. Since Elastic Beanstalk doesn't support cloud-init, you will have to build an AMI or issue a `mount` command from your code.

Comment: Hi Sergey, where/when should I put that code to mount the EFS? Should it be at the Pending Lifecycle hook? Or at some startup Linux file? Which one?